# Syncronize mask using `mask.updateValue()` to work properly. Only in Firefox

Tags: javascript

everyone!

This error is showing up in my console when I type something into the input. I am using iMask in Svelte.

```
Element value was changed outside of mask. Syncronize mask using `mask.updateValue()` to work properly.
```

Only in firefox it is causing this error. Chrome its ok.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.